# Can i pass a parameter from controller to app.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to show a start view for my ionic app if a variable is true , or show another view if the variable is false, so i need to know if i can get a parameter from a controller and use it in app.js:

```js
if (parameter===true)
  {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/inicio');
  
  }else {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/inicio2');  
  }
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You might be able to use events, but that definitely seems like the wrong way to structure your app.  Your controller shouldn't determine routing.  Also, keep in mind that until your controller executes the parameter would be undefined.

Comment: Ok i got it, have you any suggestions to do this?

Comment: Instead of this, what about using ng-include based on the parameter value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might not be the best use for providers, but it will get you what you need.

Ionic app states are defined in the module config block, and in the config block there are no controllers, no services, no factories, none of these is instantiated  yet. The only angular objects that are instantiated in the config block (beside constants) are providers. So you can create a custom provider that can get you the parameter which will tell you which view to show to the user when the app starts up. Here is how to create the provider:

```
app.provider('mainView', function MainViewProvider() {
  var someCondition = false;

  this.getCurrentMainView = function() {
    if(someCondition)
      return "/app/inicio";
    else {
      return "/app/inicio2";
    }
  };
  //return a dummy factory that will never be used or injected
  this.$get = ["nullService", function(){return null;}];

});
```

Then in your config block, inject the provider and use the `getCurrentView` function to get the URL to navigate to

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, mainViewProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(mainViewProvider.getCurrentMainView());

});
```

Comment: a suggestion, you do not need this `MainViewProvider()` in this line `app.provider('mainView', function MainViewProvider()`, by angular conventions, this `app.provider('mainView', function()` is enough, the provider name will be `mainViewProvider`, thanks again...

Comment: yeah sure, you can remove that. Thanks for pointing that to me